# Removing Items From List with Parameter of Matching String most Recent DateTime

Tags: c#, list, datetime

I am trying to narrow down a list which is comprised of all files with matching product ID (eg M320.1215). When I say I need to narrow it down I want to remove the list entries in order to keep only the most recent items in the list.

This is an example of a file name: I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_CS_07112016225939.xlsx

Here you see the Product Id as "M320.1215"
The Subformat and Language "EGHS_CS"
And a date and time 07112016225939 in format MMDDYYYYHHMMSS. I can get the date time into DateTime object using:

```
public DateTime correctedDateString(string dts)
    {
        string correctDTS = dts.Insert(2, "/");
        correctDTS = correctDTS.Insert(5, "/");
        correctDTS = correctDTS.Insert(10, " ");
        correctDTS = correctDTS.Insert(13, ":");
        correctDTS = correctDTS.Insert(16, ":");
        DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.Now;
        try
        {
            convertedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(correctDTS);
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' converts to {1} {2} time.", correctDTS, convertedDate, convertedDate.Kind.ToString());
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            convertedDate = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2015 00:00:00");
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is not in the proper format.", correctDTS);
        }
        return convertedDate;
```

This obviously a simple method.
I have been using the following to split the items in the list into usable segments:

```
string[] tempArray = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filenames[i].ToString()).ToString().Split(new[] { "_" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Now what I am struggling with is to manipulate the following list to only keep the most recent versions of each subFormat and language combo.

```
List<string> filenames = new List<string>()
        {
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_RU_07132016020215",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_BE_06292016132122",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_BE_06302016100039",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_BE_07042016080530",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_BE_07112016225936",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_BE_07132016020203",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_BR_06292016132127",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_BR_06302016100042",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_BR_07042016080536",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_BR_07112016225938",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_BR_07132016020206",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_CS_07112016225939",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_CS_07132016020207",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_DE_06292016132128",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_DE_06302016100044",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_DE_07042016080537",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_DE_07112016225940",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_DE_07132016020208",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_FR_06292016132129",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_FR_06302016100045",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_FR_07042016080538",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_FR_07112016225941",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_FR_07132016020210",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_IT_06292016132129",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_IT_06302016100046",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_IT_07042016080539",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_IT_07112016225941",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_IT_07132016020211",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_MS_06292016132130",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_MS_06302016100047",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_MS_07042016080540",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_MS_07112016225943",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_MS_07132016020212",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_PL_06292016132131",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_PL_06302016100048",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_PL_07042016080541",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_PL_07112016225944",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_PL_07132016020214",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_RU_06292016132131",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_RU_06302016100049",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_RU_07042016080542",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_RU_07112016225945"
         };
```

So essentially I need the final list to be as follows:

```
List<string> filenames = new List<string>()
        {
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_BE_07132016020203",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_BR_07132016020206",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_CS_07132016020207",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_DE_07132016020208",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_FR_07132016020210",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_IT_07132016020211",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_MS_07132016020212",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_PL_07132016020214",
            "I_ATTRIBUTES_M320.1215_EGHS_RU_07132016020215"
         };
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with Linq

```
var grouped = filenames.Select(x => x.Split('_'))
    .GroupBy(x => x[2] + x[3] + x[4], p => p, (key, g) => new { Id = key, Items = g.ToList() })
    .Select(x => x.Items.OrderByDescending(i => correctedDateString(i[5])).FirstOrDefault())
    .Select(x => string.Join("_", x))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Hi There, thank you for the feedback. I will have to read up on the Linq stuff. I am a busy teaching myself to code.

Comment: Why would your code give me an error in the OrderByDescending(correctedDateString(i => i[5])) it says something about lambda and underlines the i => i[5]?

Comment: Apologies, i corrected the code. It should be OrderByDescending(i => correctedDateString(i[5]))

Comment: Hi There, that makes a bit more sense, however this still returns the oldest and not newest. I see there is not a way to order by ascending. Is that the issue here?

Comment: Figured it out. Thank you... Used LastOrDefault() instead of FirstOrDefault().

Comment: Glad you got it working. To order asc, just change OrderByDescending() to OrderBy()

Comment: Hi There, I think the logic when dealing with the DateTime is that descending factors the date closet to today as the smallest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `List<T>.Find(Predicate<T>)` method to find the particular item and use `List<T>.Remove(T)` method to remove the selected item.

Example:

```
// Find an Employee by their ID.
Employee result = Employees.Find(
    delegate(Employee emp)
    {
        return emp.ID == IDtoFind;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = filenames.Select(s =>
{
    var splitted = s.Split('_');
    return new
    {
        ProductId = splitted[2],
        Subformat = splitted[3],
        Language = splitted[4],
        DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(splitted[5], "MMddyyyyHHmmss", null),
        Source = s
    };
})
.GroupBy(a => new { a.ProductId, a.Subformat, a.Language })
.Select(g => g.First(a => a.DateTime == g.Max(b => b.DateTime)).Source)
.ToList();
```

I'm using `DataTime.ParseExact` method instead of your `correctedDateString` method.

Comment: Hi There, your method produces results but seems not to give the most recent version of the file. It seems to just be returning the first items of each subformat and languge.

Comment: @WDavison - First max - i. e. recent. Maybe I wrong.